# cakephp: Sort pagination by individual data

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I am using CakePHP 2.3.7. To show content to the user I have a **model called contents**. The controller gets data from this model and sends it to the view by using pagination. So far, everything works fine. Now I want to show the content **in a very specific order**. For all I know I cannot use the "order"-parameter in paginate() because the order is:

1. individual for each user (and therefore not a field in the database)
2. changing frequently based on a complex calculation created on the fly
3. currently stored in a session array

I have an array containing all relevant item-IDs and a value that defines the position in the order. What I need is a way to teach the pagination to use the order I have defined in the array instead of any sortation from the database. The array I have looks like the one below, where the first number is the position in the order and the second is the ID of the item.

Is there a way to tell the pagination to use this specific item order?

```
array(
        (int) 0 => '308',
        (int) 1 => '311',
        (int) 2 => '313',
        (int) 3 => '317',
        (int) 4 => '325',
        (int) 5 => '326',
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't store the order in a session or an array but store it in the database on a per user base? After it is (re)calculated update the order information and you can use the DB's order by functionality. So either put a "position" field directly into your table or if its associated with mutliple users put it in the join table and order by this field.

[This behaviour](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils/blob/develop/Model/Behavior/ListBehavior.php) will deal with items that needs to be a list.